# Overwrite an Excel file in Google Drive using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, pydrive

I have a loop which runs through a list of files then uploads them a Google Drive folder. There is a client_secrets.json file in the folder on my computer.

I am able to create new files in the Google Drive folder but I wish to overwrite the existing files, without changing the Google Drive file IDs. Is this possible to do this adapting my code below?

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

upload_file_list ["a.xlsx", "b.xlsx"]


for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': [FOLDER ID}]})
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload()
gfile.content.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to update the existing XLSX file with a new XLSX file on Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using pydrive for python.

#### Issue and workaround:

When I saw [the document of pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html), I couldn't find the method for updating the file content while the file metadata can be updated. From your showing script, I understand that you already had the access token by the script of pydrive. So, in this answer, using your authorization script, I would like to propose a sample script for updating the file content of the file on Google Drive.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set `file_id` and `uploadXLSXfilename`.

```py
import json
import requests
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth


file_id = "###"  # Please set the file ID of the existing XLSX file on Google Drive.
uploadXLSXfilename = "./sample.xlsx"  # Please set your local XLSX file name with the path.

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
files = {
    "data": ("metadata", json.dumps({"mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}), "application/json"),
    "file": open(uploadXLSXfilename, "rb"),
}
res = requests.patch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?uploadType=multipart",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr["credentials"].access_token},
    files=files,
)
print(res.text)
```

- When this script is run, the existing file of `file_id` on Google Drive is overwritten with the local XLSX file.
- And, the access token is used from `gauth`.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than CreateFile, you [need to use update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#python)

```
service.files().update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update). Here's a sample:

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    fileId = "<ID of the file you want to update>"
    body={'name':'New name if needed'}

    # Your local file
    media_body = MediaFileUpload('Your file.xlsx',
                                mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        fileId = fileId,
        body=body,
        media_body = media_body
    ).execute()

    print(F'File ID: {updated_file.get("id")}')
```

Pretty much use your local file as `media_body` and add the necessary metadata to `body`. As explained in the documentation linked above you can modify other fields according to the [Files object documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files), which you can add to the `body` variable.

There's also a sample for the [Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#python) API, though it works a little different. My sample is for Drive v3, which is the current version.